# derivative of modulus squared

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

I have a function $f(u_q) = \sum_q K_q \mid u_q \mid^2$, where $u_q$ is a complex function. The minimum is given by $u_q = 0$, $\forall q$. Now I need a condition for this minimum to be stable. It is known that $K_q$ is real and positive. My idea is to write down a Hessian and show that the eigenvalues are positive definite. I guess these eigenvalues are then proportional to $K_q$, meaning that $K_q > 0$, $\forall q$. However, I am not sure if this is true, since I do not know how to take second derivatives of a modulus squared.

Comment: What, precisely, do you mean by $d^2f/dz^2$?

Comment: The second derivative of $f$ with respect to $z$.

Comment: But what do you mean, precisely, by "derivative of $f$ with respect to $z$"?

Comment: I do not really understand your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I changed my question, hope it is more clear now.